# Pandas find average for string occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm working with a dataframe to try to find averages and am stuck when trying to turn value counts into averages for my grouped df.  Code is below:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['school', 'Race/Ethnicity']).size()

school          Race/Ethnicity                        
school1         African American/Black                     15
                American Indian/Alaska Native               1
                Bi-racial/Multi-racial                      4
                Latino/a                                   53
                Other - Write In (Required)                 1
                White                                       2
school2         African American/Black                      1
                American Indian/Alaska Native               5
                Asian                                       1
                Bi-Racial/Multi-Racial                      1
                Latino/a                                   26
```

I have a lot of different schools, and instead of size I want to find the mean for each race of each school.  How do I iterate over the groups to find the sum of each group and then divide each line by its group's sum?

Comment: It would be helpful to see sample data but it sounds like you can just divide `df2` by `df.groupby('school').size()`.

Comment: @AndrewL Thank you, that's exactly what I needed! I knew I was making things way harder than they needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `normalize` parameter in `value_counts`

```
df.groupby('school')['Race/Ethnicity'].value_counts(normalize=True)

school   Race/Ethnicity               
school1  Latino/a                         0.697368
         African American/Black           0.197368
         Bi-racial/Multi-racial           0.052632
         White                            0.026316
         American Indian/Alaska Native    0.013158
         Other - Write In (Required)      0.013158
school2  Latino/a                         0.764706
         American Indian/Alaska Native    0.147059
         African American/Black           0.029412
         Asian                            0.029412
         Bi-Racial/Multi-Racial           0.029412
Name: Race/Ethnicity, dtype: float64
```

---

You can also skip the sorting

```
df.groupby('school')['Race/Ethnicity'].value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False)

school   Race/Ethnicity               
school1  African American/Black           0.197368
         American Indian/Alaska Native    0.013158
         Bi-racial/Multi-racial           0.052632
         Latino/a                         0.697368
         Other - Write In (Required)      0.013158
         White                            0.026316
school2  African American/Black           0.029412
         American Indian/Alaska Native    0.147059
         Asian                            0.029412
         Bi-Racial/Multi-Racial           0.029412
         Latino/a                         0.764706
Name: Race/Ethnicity, dtype: float64
```

---

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['school1', 'African American/Black']] * 15 +
    [['school1', 'American Indian/Alaska Native']] * 1 + 
    [['school1', 'Bi-racial/Multi-racial']] * 4 +
    [['school1', 'Latino/a']] * 53 +
    [['school1', 'Other - Write In (Required)']] * 1 +
    [['school1', 'White']] * 2 +
    [['school2', 'African American/Black']] * 1 +
    [['school2', 'American Indian/Alaska Native']] * 5 +
    [['school2', 'Asian']] * 1 +
    [['school2', 'Bi-Racial/Multi-Racial']] * 1 +
    [['school2', 'Latino/a']] * 26,
    columns=['school', 'Race/Ethnicity']
)
```